# Defining Property Names in multiple LinQ-Connections

Tags: c#, linq

I have to following "Address" - Table with those fields:

```
[Id] int
[FirstName] nvarchar
[LastName] nvarchar
[Street] nvarchar
```

Now I have the following "User"-Table which has multiple foreign key to the address-Table

```
[ShippingAddressId] ->Address
[BillingAddressId] ->Address
[PrivateAddressId] ->Address
[Username] nvarchar
```

When I use LinQ and include those tables, the designer creates the following properties:

```
int ShippingAddressId
int BillingAddressId
int PrivateAddressId

Address Address, // for ShippingAddress
Address Address1 // for BillingAddress
Address Address2 // for PrivateAddress
```

Having "Address1" and "Address2" isn't just ugly, It also happened that after doing changes in the datastructure and recreating the designer files they swapped the content (Address3 suddenly containing shippingAddress and Address2 containing the Billingaddress and so on)

So is there a clean way to hint the designer to use better property names?
If not: What would be your suggestion? Derive from the designer class and implement my own properties? How do I make sure there it uses the "right" property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in the properties view (in Visual Studio) for the selected relationship/connection, you can expand the parent and child items to edit the referential names.

You can't, however, account for some of the mishaps that happen in DBML generation, though, especially the more complex the thing gets - so prepare to do it 'right first time' and make notes in case you end up having to select all -> delete -> recreate.

So long as your relations are each well named, keeping track of editing the fields they are bound to is easy using the same view mentioned.

Comment: Looks like this is the best solution I can get. At least the backend will throw errors when I forget correct naming after DB changes because the properties cannot be found. Better than nothing.

Comment: It can be productive, but can also be infuriating using the VS DBML designer; I'd spec out and get your structure correct, design it using the database engine manager/front-end/script it; only then drag and drop in the VS designer. That's where making notes of changes to 'friendly names' comes in handy: it can often be easier after a change (if needed at all) to clear the DBML and drag the lot back on, renaming the noted changes.  Seems long-winded, but there are much less productive ways.